# Is there a way to know ho many of my comments have a score of 5 or more to obtain the Pundit badge?

Tags: support, badges

I understand badges are a way for users to track their achievements while helping the community. Usually there is a way for the user to know how far he is from obtaining a new badge, specially for those badges that require you to do a determined amount of *X* (being *X* upvotes on questions or answers, for instance). Specific for the [Pundit badge](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/badges/56/pundit) the user is required to have 10 or more comments with a score of 5 or higher.

My question is: is there a way for a user to know how many of his comments have a score of 5 or higher? I'm aware that there is a *comments* tab under *all actions*, but it only shows my comments, not their present score.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For such question, there is [data.SE](http://data.stackexchange.com). Apparently, someone thought about it too, so there is [a query for this badge](http://data.stackexchange.com/travel/query/293394/how-long-until-i-get-the-pundit-badge). I let you run it with your user id and on the right site. I suppose you can search on data.SE for any badge, someone probably wrote a query for it.

As you mentioned, the query did not order the comments as one can expect. I clicked on the column to sort it as I wished. But a better way is I forked the query and edited it for the right purpose: [here you can see your sorted comments](http://data.stackexchange.com/travel/query/314320/how-long-until-i-get-the-pundit-badge?UserId=24596). Feel free to fork it and customize it as you like, the language is standard or close to standard SQL, and the tables are described on the right panel.

Good luck catching the badge, apparently you're on the right track!

Comment: Nice! I didn't know about data SE. Only one thing, the comment to the query you provided says "List comments in order of score", but it's order by clause is "ORDER BY Posts.ParentId,Posts.Id", so it is actually ordering by a comment's ids and not by it's score. Can the query be fixed? If yes,how to do it?

Comment: @gmauch there are multiple ways, I updated the answer with the forked query.